# Error Docker starting same container twice

Tags: docker, docker-compose

i am trying to start a repo which was running fine previously but now when i use `docker-compose up` or `--build` also it create the network driver and then create the sqs_1 twice leading to this error

```
Creating evalai-ngx_sqs_1 …
Creating evalai-ngx_sqs_1 … error
WARNING: Host is already in use by another container

ERROR: for evalai-ngx_sqs_1 Cannot start service sqs: driver failed programming external  connectivity on endpoint evalai-ngx_sqs_1 (5103436ff627cbbafe1bde3592eac4b0c654bdb8f19f700e864bc2278b98f459): Bind for 0.0.0.0:9324 failed: port is already allocated
Creating evalai-ngx_db_1 … error

ERROR: for evalai-ngx_db_1 Cannot start service db: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint evalai-ngx_db_1 (d0d92e2e853b3d07924be9c66f97c5093a843e0ffab9d929e4dfb7f6bc8870e0): Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:5432: bind: address already in use

ERROR: for sqs Cannot start service sqs: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint evalai-ngx_sqs_1 (5103436ff627cbbafe1bde3592eac4b0c654bdb8f19f700e864bc2278b98f459): Bind for 0.0.0.0:9324 failed: port is already allocated

ERROR: for db Cannot start service db: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint evalai-ngx_db_1 (d0d92e2e853b3d07924be9c66f97c5093a843e0ffab9d929e4dfb7f6bc8870e0): Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:5432: bind: address already in use
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
```

I Tried to remove the container , stop it and i even tried prune and unistalled docker once but still it is same.

Comment: Give us your compose file and your containers `docker container ls -a` and your networks `docker network ls` to have a clue whats going on.

Comment: For anyone who stumbles across this and is using more than one service sharing the same port within your docker compose file, then ensure that you're using the hostname option: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#domainname-hostname-ipc-mac_address-privileged-read_only-shm_size-stdin_open-tty-user-working_dir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I previously install postgresql which was indeed disturbing  with my db service now i disable it